# how to trigger ID one by one

Tags: jquery, triggers

frist check this `http://jsfiddle.net/jQFWM` .. this is working perfectly. but i don't want to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#panel-1").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });

    $(".btn-slide2").click(function(){
        $("#panel-2").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });  
    $(".btn-slide3").click(function(){
        $("#panel-3").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });  
});
```

write like that. because i don't want to repate same code again and again. also in the future this panel and tiggering will be dynamic so it will be more than 3. so what is in my mind if i can trigger that by calling number say like 1, 2, 3 etc then can code will be small i guess. so guys any idea how ? like  $("#panel+number")

`http://jsfiddle.net/jQFWM/1` this one short code but not working.

Comment: what I would suggest is giving always the same class to that button. Then add click event to that class, and in the event, you can toggle class on the button using "this" , and find the parent panel using jquery traversing functions; That way you don't have to deal with numbers and so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

JS:

```
$(".combtn a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#panel-" + $(this).data('panel')).slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

$('.btn-slide').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.panbox').slideToggle("slow");
    $(".combtn a").removeClass("active");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="combtn"><a href="#" data-panel="1">panel 1</a>
<div class="combtn"><a href="#" data-panel="2">panel 2</a>
<div class="combtn"><a href="#" data-panel="3">panel 3</a>
```

Panel Close:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-slide">close</a>
```

This uses the `data-*` attribute to store the panel number. I've also simplified the classes so that you don't have to add extra events or class names for every panel you add.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/jQFWM/2/

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires no IDs or numerical links. The elements are related by parent-child rather than hard coded IDs.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jQFWM/3/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="combtn"><a href="#" class="btn-slide">panel 1</a>
    <div id="panel-1" class="panbox"> testing panle 1
      <p><a href="#" class="btn-slide close">close</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="combtn"><a href="#" class="btn-slide">panel 2</a>
    <div id="panel-2" class="panbox"> testing panle 2
      <p><a href="#" class="btn-slide close">close</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="combtn"><a href="#" class="btn-slide">panel 3</a>
    <div id="panel-3" class="panbox"> testing panle 3
      <p><a href="#" class="btn-slide close">close</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.combtn').find('.panbox').slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give arguments into your function an grab them in a global variable:

```
<a class="btn-slide1" href="#" onclick="toggler('panel-1');">Click me for 1</a>
<a class="btn-slide2" href="#" onclick="toggler('panel-2');">Click me for 2</a>
<a class="btn-slide3" href="#" onclick="toggler('panel-3');">Click me for 3</a>
```

and write a function:

```
var currentpanel;  
function toggler(e){
    currentpanel = $('#'+e);
    currentpanel.slideToggle("slow");
    currentpanel.toggleClass("active"); 
    return false;
});
```